# Logstash json field convert

Tags: json, logstash

Logstash is receiving a json input from filebeat. It then parses the json.

```
filter {
  json {
    source => "message"
    target => "data"
  }
}
```

This data then goes to elastic search. All which works perfectly.

Now I need to convert some of the json fields.

e.g. data.body_bytes_sent must be converted to an integer.

I know there is a convert in logstash which converts fields:

```
filter {
  mutate {
    convert => { "msgSubmissionTime" => "integer" }
  }
}
```

But how do I tell it to convert a field in the parsed json object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked:

```
filter {
  json {
    source => "message"
    target => "data"
  }
  mutate {
    convert => {"[data][body_bytes_sent]" => "integer"}
    convert => {"[data][bytes_sent]" => "integer"}
  }
}
```